# signer certificate in javafx 2.1

Tags: certificate, javafx-2, javafx, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans on windows 7 and javafx and when I run the program this message appear in output ,

```
Warning: 
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
Enter Passphrase for keystore: Enter key password for nb-jfx: 
Signing JAR:
C:\Users\subhi\Desktop\SpeechRecognition\SpeechRecognition\dist\lib\batch.jar to 
C:\Users\subhi\Desktop\SpeechRecognition\SpeechRecognition\dist\lib\batch.jar as nb-jfx
```

1. There is 5 similar messages and these slow my application startup, I want to disable them , how can I do that ?
2. Can I use eclipse with javafx 2.1?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I want to disable them , how can I do that ?

Disable jar packaging and signing for your build.

1. Right click on the project, choose Properties.
2. Choose Build | Packaging and make sure "Build Jar after compiling" is not checked.
3. Choose Build | Deployment and make sure that "Request unrestricted access" is not checked.
4. Press OK to close the project properties dialog.
5. Press F6 to run your project and make sure it still runs.
6. Modify a file and try running it again with F6 to feel the speed . . .

For distribution packaging you may want to re-enable some of these options, but if your app works without them when you are in development mode and it speeds up your development, then disabling them for development is a good idea.

> can I use eclipse with javafx 2.1?

Yes, use the [e(fx)clipse plugin](http://efxclipse.org/).

Comment: hello there ,I cannot post new Question , what is the problem that I made ?

Comment: Sorry forsubhi, but I have no idea why you can't post new questions.

Comment: I receive this error Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.